# How can I smooth an diagonal line edge?

Tags: modeling, vertices, smooth

I am new to Blender and I am trying to create a simple character. I want to have a kimono like dress.

I duplicate the body, applied a *Solidify* modifier and then scale so I can conform to the body shape. I want to have a diagonal cut/shape. I tried deleting the faces and edit the vertices to give it the shape but I do not get a smooth line.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Underlying geometry:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you please disable the solidify modifier and provide another image. Your underlying topology might be the reason for this jaggedness.

Comment: Just added the picture of the underlying topology. I disabled solidify and subdivision modifiers. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying topology is the issue. The faces near the border contain triangles and  n-gons. When the subdivision surface modifier does it's work, it creates a mess. Triangles and n-gons should be used only where necessary where necessary.
Below I have put some images and also a solution.

This is your current mesh.
[image]

This is what happens when solidified

[image]

And this is what happens when subsurf does it's job
[image]
Subsurf with optimal display turned off (To understand how the faces are subdivided)
[image]

(Now please keep in mind that there are better ways to solve this problem. But this one will do a good job too. I cannot get too specific as your model is different than what I have created for representation purpose)
Using the knife tool cut the faces, and delete certain edges to make sure that the all the faces near the border are quads only. The faces next to the border should be preferably quads, but triangle can be okay.(Depends entire on the model)

Below is what is did:
[image]
Final Result:
[image]

(Once again, there are better ways to handle this issue. But things always depend on the model)

Comment: Excellent! thank you very much! I will give it a try and let you know. Much appreciated!